# abline command fitting incorrect

Tags: r, best-fit

I am trying to use the command abline to fit a line and find an R-squared value for a relationship between columns from two different data sources. 
My data manipulation is as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(prop=as.numeric(as.character(prop$factorised column)), spv=column_from_a_matrix[,1]) #align the columns

df<-subset(df, !is.na(df$prop) & df$prop!=0.00) # 'as.numeric(as.character' introduces NA 
                                                # values by coercion and get rid of 0's
with(df, plot(prop, spv))
abline(fit <- lm(prop ~ spv, data=df), col='red')
legend("topright", bty="n", legend=paste("R2 is", format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=4)))
```

However the produced line is clearly wrong:

[image]

```
 summary(lm(prop ~ spv, data=df))

 Call:
 lm(formula = prop ~ spv, data = df)

 Residuals:
   Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
 -3.6856794 -0.9907636 -0.3290975  0.6782148  7.7086112 

 Coefficients:
                 Estimate  Std. Error  t value               Pr(>|t|)    
  (Intercept)  2.78546164  0.07840516 35.52651 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
  spv         22.61806073  2.18325279 10.35980 < 0.000000000000000222 ***
  ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Residual standard error: 1.633367 on 432 degrees of freedom
 Multiple R-squared:  0.1989994,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1971452 
 F-statistic: 107.3254 on 1 and 432 DF,  p-value: < 0.00000000000000022204
```

As I do not get any errors I can not see where I'm going wrong even though the relationship is clearly wrong.....

The output of dput(df) is:

```
    structure(list(prop = c(1.4, 2.5, 2.6, 3.3, 1.63, 0.9, 2.22, 2.43, 0.64, 1.4, 3.1, 0.41..... 
    spv = c(0.0636986180909399, -0.0596651855579327..... 
    .Names = c("prop", "spv"), 
    row.names = c(3L, 4L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 24L ....
```

My research of the abline command has just told me that exactly what I'm doing is right.... can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think abline is doing it wrong. The slope is 22 which will be very steep on that y-scale. Please can you provide some data with `dput` to make the problem reproducible

Comment: Hi Richard sorry I'm not familiar with the command dput- should that be dput(df)?, the output of which is:  

structure(list(prop = c(1.4, 2.5, 2.6, 3.3, 1.63, 0.9, 2.22, 2.43, 0.64, 1.4, 3.1, 0.41..... spv = c(0.0636986180909399, -0.0596651855579327..... .Names = c("prop", "spv"), row.names = c(3L, 4L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 24L .....

Comment: `abline(fit <- lm(prop ~ spv, data=df), col='red')` -- why this way? you have `spv` on y-axis , so you what you want should be `abline(lm(spv ~ prop, data=df), col='red')`. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: anothe thing -> fitting is done by `lm` rather than `abline` - the latter just draws a line

Comment: @johnnyutah You have to copy&paste the complete `dput()` output. ^

Comment: Hi @lebatsnok, that solved the problem- right of course I'm embarrassed now thanks